# Matlab does not recognizes function

Tags: matlab

I'm using preaty old Matlab  (version 7.1.0.246 (R14) Service Pack 3) :(

I have some toolbox I was provided which I'd like to use. When I try to execute the function, I'm getting `Undefined command/function 'test'` (my function is `test` and stored in `test.m` and the file located in my current working directory).

If I place the file in `C:\Temp\` and execute `which test`, I'm getting the complete file path (`C:\Temp\test.m`).

If I place the file in `C:\Temp\MyMap\` and execute `which test`, I'm getting the complete file path('C:\Temp\MyMap\test.m') and  additional comment `%Has no license available`.

If I use following one

```
if exist('test')
    test(...)
end
```

It solves the issue. However, as mentioned previously, its a toolbox and contains many functions. I don't have time (and want to) apply the workaround on all the files/functions.

Any suggestion how this could be solved?

Comment: There's lots to unpack here... you said you're using a "pretty old" MATLAB - please actually state the version. Although that seems irrelevant because your issue is with a custom function not being found, which should be independent of MATLAB version - please show the actual full path outputs you're getting for `which`, also run `which test -all` to show all versions on your path. Then it's not clear why you'd get a message about licensing from _any_ function, so you need to provide the full error message inc. stack trace to help identify the difference. Please [edit] your question

Comment: @Wolfie Done.
There is no difference between the `which test -all` and `which test`